# ¿Como agregarle más datos a un objecto en java?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa

Tengo una consulta que trae unos detos de JPA, como puede agregarle más datos a un objecto en java por ejemplo tengo este array de objecto que lo trae esta consulta:

```
[
    {
        "dato": {
            "nombre": 'maria',
            "edad": 23
        },
        "pais": 'chile,
        "sexo": 'F'
    },
    {
      "dato": {
            "nombre": 'carmen',
            "edad": 22
        },
        "pais": 'colombia',
        "sexo": 'F'
    },
    {
            "dato": {
            "nombre": 'mario',
            "edad": 33
        },
        "pais": 'china',
        "sexo": 'M'
    }
]
```

*Lo que necesito, es poder agregarle a la consulta unos datos que no estan en la base de datos, quiero poder agregarle unos datos al JSON como se muestra en el ejemplo:*

```
[
    {
        "dato": {
            "nombre": 'maria',
            "edad": 23,
            

        },
        "pais": 'chile,
        "sexo": 'F',
        "estado_civil": 'soltero'
    },
    {
      "dato": {
            "nombre": 'carmen',
            "edad": 22,
            
        },
        "pais": 'colombia',
        "sexo": 'F',
       "estado_civil": 'soltero'
    },
    {
            "dato": {
            "nombre": 'mario',
            "edad": 33
        },
        "pais": 'china',
        "sexo": 'M', 
        "estado_civil": 'soltero'

    }
]
```

En la última parte de array de objecto de agrego el campo "estado_civil": 'soltero' alguna idea

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la libreria Gson

```
String json1 = "[{\"dorsal\":6," + "\"name\":\"Iniesta\","
            + "\"demarcation\":[\"Right winger\",\"Midfielder\"],"
            + "\"team\":\"FC Barcelona\"}]";

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    // Obtain Array
    JsonArray gsonArr = parser.parse(json1).getAsJsonArray();

    // for each element of array
    for (JsonElement obj : gsonArr) {

        // Object of array
        JsonObject gsonObj = obj.getAsJsonObject();

        // Primitives elements of object
        int dorsal = gsonObj.get("dorsal").getAsInt();
        String name = gsonObj.get("name").getAsString();
        String team = gsonObj.get("team").getAsString();

        // List of primitive elements
        JsonArray demarcation = gsonObj.get("demarcation").getAsJsonArray();
        List listDemarcation = new ArrayList();
        for (JsonElement demarc : demarcation) {
            listDemarcation.add(demarc.getAsString());
        }

        // Object Constructor
        FootballPlayer iniesta = new FootballPlayer(dorsal, name,
                listDemarcation, team);
        System.out.println(iniesta);
    }
```

Aqui el link con el ejemplo: https://jarroba.com/gson-json-java-ejemplos/

Answer (score 0):

Para una Entity de JPA puedes crear campos que no estén en la BD, para ignorarlos usa [@Transient](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html), si el dato de estado civil lo obtienes de otra BD u otra entidad, te animaría a tratar de trabajar con la dependencia normalmente y usar un [DTO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objeto_de_transferencia_de_datos) para retornar el objeto tal cual lo necesitas, [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) te puede ayudar en eso.